# How does one measure anti-neutrino flavor oscillation probabilities?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, cp-violation

The Dirac $CP$ phase $\delta_{CP}$ in the $U_{PMNS}$ mixing matrix lead to the $CP$-violation in the Lepton sector. I think this can be tested by comparing neutrino flavour oscillation probabilities with anti-neutrino flavour oscillation probabilities. If only neutrinos are produced in Sun but not antineutrinos, how can one measure and compare two probabilities?

Comment: Ideally you use an accelerator source of neutrinos (e.g. what HyperK and DUNE plan to use) and reverse the polarity of the 'horn' to choose neutrinos or antineutrinos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anti-neutrinos are produce in copious quantities by nuclear reactors, in the atmospheric interactions of cosmic rays and can be [produced on-demand at accelerators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/how-are-neutrino-beams-emitted-at-cern). Indeed, given [the nature of the interaction of normal and anti-neutrinos it is arguable that anti-neutrinos are easier to deal with experimentally at low energies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245963/how-to-observe-neutrinos).

It is worth noting that [the first unambiguous observation of neutrino interactions was of reactor anti-neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262251/why-was-the-first-discovered-neutrino-an-anti-neutrino).

But so far the available data simply isn't precise enough to detect a difference between matter-type and antimatter-type neutrino oscillation parameters.. This is something that the community has been building up to for some time. I think the smart money right now is on NO$\nu$A, and if they have some unexpected problem DUNE will be along to lend a hand.

One of the interesting issues is that some of the data has good resolution in $\Delta m$ and poor resolution in $\theta$ and other data sets turn that around. [If you combine them under the assumption of CP symmetry then you get a good overall result](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/solar-neutrino-predictions), but of course that won't tell you that if CP is violated. Here's a figure from a KamLAND paper showing how this works:

[image]

(Figure from https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.221803 )

Comment: But how would you know the solar mixing angle $\theta^{\bar{\nu}}_{12}$ for anti-neutrino flavor oscillation?

Comment: You measure the long-component of the reactor oscillation with a detector like, say, KamLAND (which I was a part of for a while) and of the atmospheric behavior with detectors like SNO and Super-K. Neutrinos are an industry in particle physics with nearly 20 years of serious work under our belts and a similar amount planned.